# how to use useState on loop react functional component

Tags: reactjs

How to use useState for below loop React functional component or

OnClick set className if  correct= 1 "answer correct" and correct= 0 "js-choose-answer wrong"

```
 {users?.map((user,index)=>{
    <div onClick={handleForm} correct={user.opt1 == user.ans?'1':0 } className="answer"><div>a</div>{user.opt1}</div></div>
    <div onClick={handleForm} correct={user.opt2 == user.ans?'1':0 } className="answer"><div>b</div>{user.opt2}</div></div>
    <div onClick={handleForm} correct={user.opt3 == user.ans?'1':0 } className="answer"><div>c</div>{user.opt3}</div></div>
     <div onClick={handleForm} correct={user.opt4 == user.ans?'1':0 } className="answer"><div>d</div>{user.opt4}</div></div>
         })}
```

its loop

Answer (score 1):

You can use this function to updated a JSON state:

```
export const changeJsonState = (oldValues, type, newValue) => {
  return { ...oldValues, [type]: newValue };
};
```